# QML - ListView item which displays a menu on tap

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

I'm looking for some tips and pointers on displaying a menu underneath a list Item when a user taps on the Item.

If I have a ListModel like this:

```
ListModel {
    ListElement {
        name: "Bill Smith"
        number: "555 3264"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "John Brown"
        number: "555 8426"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Sam Wise"
        number: "555 0473"
    }
}
```

Then a ListView like so:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 180; height: 200

    Component {
        id: contactDelegate
        Item {
            width: 180; height: 40
            Column {
                Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name }
                Text { text: '<b>Number:</b> ' + number }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ContactModel {}
        delegate: contactDelegate
        highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
        focus: true
    }
}
```

Then when a user taps on an Item I want to display a menu:

```
Menu {
    id: menu
    MenuItem { text: "item1" }
    MenuItem { text: "item2"; }
    MenuItem { text: "item3"; }
}
```

Looking at some other QML samples I've found some code which adds a MouseArea and positions the menu based on Window - Menu height and width:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        menu.x = (window.width - menu.width) / 2
        menu.y = (window.height - menu.height) / 2
        menu.open();
    }
}
```

However I'm struggling to get it working, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could explain what you want to get, your explanation can be interpreted in several ways.

Comment: I'd like the menu to be positioned underneath the list item that was tapped on. Directly underneath it.

Comment: Where did you place the `MouseArea` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is established that the parent of the Menu is the ListView, then it will only suffice to establish a relative position of the item pressed through `mapToItem`:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 180; height: 200

    Component {
        id: contactDelegate
        Item {
            width: 180; height: 40
            Column {
                Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name }
                Text { text: '<b>Number:</b> ' + number }
            }

            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked:  {
                    var pos = mapToItem(listView, 0, height)
                    menu.x = pos.x
                    menu.y = pos.y
                    menu.open()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        objectName: "list"
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ContactModel{}
        delegate: contactDelegate
        focus: true

        Menu {
            id: menu
            MenuItem { text: "item1" }
            MenuItem { text: "item2"; }
            MenuItem { text: "item3"; }
        }

    }
}
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48874873).